# ¿Como redireccionar con htaccess sin que me dé error?

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

Buenos días!
Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:
Tengo una url, (http://subdominio.holamundo.com/admin) y quiero que cuando el cliente entre a esa url, se le redirija automáticamente a http://subdominio.holamundo.com/admin/panel.

Es decir:

```
http://subdominio.holamundo.com/admin => http://subdominio.holamundo.com/admin/panel
```

He buscado en internet y se supone que la solucion es un htacces con:

```
301 /admin http://subdominio.holamundo.com/admin/panel
```

Me da error 500 Internal Server Error

Notas:
La web está hecha con codeigniter.
El archivo htacess lo he puesto en la raiz de la web

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
301 /admin http://subdominio.holamundo.com/admin/panel
```

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal... =(

Answer (score 1):

Al final he encontrado una solución después de volverme loco buscando.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
RedirectMatch 301 /admin/^ http://subdominio.holamundo.com/admin/panel
```